# Move Fabric JS Canvas on page

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is there a way that I can move the entire FabricJS Canvas to another location on the page instead of having it the default fixed location?

Comment: did you solve this problem @user5749747 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change top and left properties of canvas container using jQuery.